# Extract postcards from a scanned document using opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, scanning

I have 1000s of old postcards that I'd like to scan, and I think it might be a good idea to optimize my workflow using some kind of automatic crop/rotate tools, so I have started investigating OpenCV with Python.

Below is a sample of picture I can acquire using my scanner:

[image: Sample scan]

As you can imagine, my goal is to create, from this image, three images each containing one postcard. I have tried many OpenCV options and the best code I have been able to get so far is:

```
import cv2, sys, imutils

cv2.namedWindow('image', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

image = cv2.imread("sample1600.jpg")
ratio = image.shape[0] / 300.0
image = imutils.resize(image, height = 800)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
ret, th = cv2.threshold(gray, 220, 235, 1)
edged = cv2.Canny(th, 25, 200)

(cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:5]

for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.05 * peri, True)

    if len(approx) == 4:
        cv2.drawContours(image, [approx], -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)

cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The produced image is:

[image: Resulting picture]

The issue with this code is that:

- it does not find the bottom image which is too close to the border;
- It only works for my test image, but it does not seem to be very generic. The line "ret, th = cv2.threshold(gray, 220, 235, 1)", for example, will prevent things from working on an image that has a different histogram I believe.

What is the best way to make this code work better and be more generic to fulfill my requirement to process scanned images?

Individual postcards should have a ratio that is approximatively √2 between width and height. That won't always be the case, but if my script is able to deal efficiently with this type of postcards, I will be more than happy (they represent more than 99% of my collection).

Thanks to @Riccardo, I now have a script that works for my first sample image, so adding a new one in order to try to find a more robust solution:

[image: Sample with less contrast]

As @Riccardo has been very efficient providing a solution for the two first samples, here are two others that seem to be a bit more complicated because of the limited space between image for this first one:

[image: Overlapping image]

Or cards that are almost blank for some parts:

[image: A lot of blank]

Comment: BTW, you might want to scan to PNG and only encode the final processed postcard images to JPEG, to avoid quality degradation due to repeated lossy compression. | Too close to edge -- if you're in control of the scanning process you could place them better -- e.g. rotating the bottom one 90 degrees would yield a much better fit with nice margins. | After you `threshold`, use [`cv2.copyMakeBorder`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga2ac1049c2c3dd25c2b41bffe17658a36) to add some extra background around the image to avoid the "too close to border" issue.

Comment: Thanks @Dan Mašek : I will be in control of the scanning process but my goal is to put 4 pictures in the scanner so rotating the bottom one is not possible. Regarding the png/jpg question, it seems from the tests I have been able to do that it does not affect the quality of the results I can get so far.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would suggest to pass through the computation of the rotated bounding box of the contour instead of trying to identify fixed shapes.
In my try, the script identifies a box-like figure and calculates its contourArea, then it selects the figures that possess a big area.

This should solve your problem, let us know if it doesn't.

```
cv2.namedWindow('image', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

image = cv2.imread("sample1600.jpg")
ratio = image.shape[0] / 300.0
image = imutils.resize(image, height = 800)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)


ret, th = cv2.threshold(gray,220,235,1)
edged = cv2.Canny(th, 25, 200)

im2, cnts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE,   cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)

for c in cnts:
    box = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
    box = cv2.cv.BoxPoints(box) if imutils.is_cv2() else cv2.boxPoints(box)
    box = np.array(box, dtype="int")
    if cv2.contourArea(box) > 70000:
        cv2.drawContours(image, [box], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This is the output:
[image]

EDIT:
I don't know if this is the right solution, probably there are some other. I encourage the other users to share their approaches.
@Sylvain, here's another try with some tuning of the parameters:

- decreasing of the threshold to 210;
- removing of the canny function (it messes with the complex patterns of some images;
- calculation of the image area and playing around with the limit of the contour to be returned. In this particular example I imposed the contour to be larger than 1/10 of the image and smaller than 2/3.

  ```
  image = cv2.imread(img)

  gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)

  ret, th = cv2.threshold(gray,210,235,1)

  im2, cnts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(th.copy(),cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
  cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)

  for c in cnts:
      box = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
      box = cv2.cv.BoxPoints(box) if imutils.is_cv2() else cv2.boxPoints(box)
      box = np.array(box, dtype="int")
      Area = image.shape[0]*image.shape[1]
      if Area/10 < cv2.contourArea(box) < Area*2/3:
          cv2.drawContours(image, [box], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

  cv2.imshow("Image", image)
  cv2.waitKey(0)
  ```

Comment: Thanks @Riccardo that's a great enhancement to my original version. That works fine on this first image but still misses some cards on the [new sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pG78a.jpg) I have added to my original post. If you have any idea on how to fix that it would be great! Anyway, already a big thank for this first answer, was not hoping for a working solution so fast.

Comment: glad to be useful. I'm workin on this topics and I found your question quite challenging

Comment: Thanks @Riccardo, I will mark this answer as correct as it already fixes two of my images. But if you want some more challenge, I have added two other samples that seem to be more complicated or at least are not yet handle by the latest version of your code.

Comment: I'm sure you can solve this problem by yourself, just tune the parameters as I did and the results will arrive. Enjoy